# Acessing java cache from a java applet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, applet, jvm, japplet

I would like to know if is possible to access the cache from java directly from an applet in a dynamic way, in other word the applet must work in multiple OS.

All of this because i want to load a file at java cache in order to not have to download the file everytime the applet is loaded.

This is what i have for now:

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL( "http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~aaugusto/libpcsclite.so");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();
        File file = new File("libpcsclite.so");
        System.out.println(file.length()+" "+file.exists());
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        //int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int downloadedSize = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer
        while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
        }
        fileOutput.close();
        System.out.println(file.length()+" DAMN "+file.getPath());
        System.out.print(file.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

ps: i cannot use JNLP. I have certificates to sign the applet

Best regards,

Comment: download it to the same folder, or some temporary folder. next time check if file is there.

Comment: I do not like the idea of writing in other user paths... I was trying to access the cache path but the absolute path varies from os. and users can even change the cache path... :/